# Consume nodejs library from Rust

Tags: node.js, rust

I need to use an existing *nodejs* library from my Rust project and I am thinking of adding the node library as a *git subtree* and execute `node whatever.js` commands from Rust. But this doesn't seem ideal to me...

Is there any better way of embedding a *nodejs* library in my Rust project so I can call functions from that library in my Rust application?

Answer (score -1):

Ended up using IPC between Rust and Node.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the solution? What IPC?